# Derivative of matrix-vector products w.r.t. the matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Given the function $$F(X,Y,Z) = \alpha^TXYZ$$ in which $X, Y, Z $ are matrices of size $n \times n$ and $\alpha$ is a vector of size $n \times 1$, how to compute the derivative of $F$ with respect to $Y$?

Actually I found some related questions but did not help.

Edit: if the function is of the form: $F(X,Y,Z) = \alpha^TXYZ\beta$, then based on the Matrix Cookbook, derivative is : $f' = (\alpha^T X)^T (Z\beta)^T$, but if there is no $\beta$, then the dimensions do not match.

Thank you,

Comment: Why the downvote? I thought this is perfectly valid question as the rule for matrix derivatives can be rather confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let ${\mathcal E}$ be the 4th-order tensor with components
$$\eqalign{
{\mathcal E}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jl} \cr
}$$
Using this tensor, we can calculate the differential and gradient of the function as
$$\eqalign{
 f &= a^TXYZ \cr
\cr
df &= a^T(X\,dY\,Z) \cr
   &= a^T(X\,{\mathcal E}\,Z^T):dY \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}&= a^TX\,{\mathcal E}\,Z^T \cr
}$$
As expected, the gradient of a vector wrt a matrix is a 3rd-order tensor.

If you are unable to work with tensors, you can vectorize the differential to obtain
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(df) &= {\rm vec}(a^TX\,dY\,Z) \cr
 df &= (Z^T\otimes a^TX)\,{\rm vec}(dY) \cr
    &= (Z^T\otimes a^TX)\,dy \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}&= Z^T\otimes a^TX \cr
}$$
which is an ordinary matrix quantity.

This is equivalent to the previous result, if you swap the order of the factors and replace the kronecker product symbol with the ${\mathcal E}$ tensor.

Comment: Hmmmm I am curious. Where can I read more about tensor in this context?

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I got it. I am also interested in learning more about tensors...

Comment: Just work through the problem in index notation, and you'll see what's happening.  This particular tensor is good to know about because it occurs so frequently. It is useful for rearranging the order a regular matrix product $$AXB=A{\mathcal E}B^T:X=X:A^T{\mathcal E}B$$ It is also the identity element for the inner (Frobenius) product, $$X:{\mathcal E}={\mathcal E}:X=X$$ There's a related tensor ${\mathcal B}_{ijkl}=\delta_{il}\,\delta_{jk}$ whose action is to transpose a matrix $$X^T={\mathcal B}:X=X:{\mathcal B}$$ which also comes in handy.

Comment: @greg if I want to take the derivative with respect to $Z$, then should I use the outer product of the eye matrix with $a^T XY$?

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$\rm f (X, Y, Z) := a^{\top} X Y Z$$

Hence,

$$\frac{\mathrm f (\mathrm X, \mathrm Y + h \mathrm V, \mathrm Z) - \mathrm f (\mathrm X, \mathrm Y, \mathrm Z)}{h} = \rm a^{\top} X V Z$$

Vectorizing,

$$\rm \mbox{vec} (a^{\top} X V Z) = \left( \color{blue}{Z^{\top} \otimes a^{\top} X}  \right) \mbox{vec} (V)$$

where $\rm Z^{\top} \otimes a^{\top} X$ is the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: This is the same result Greg obtained.